# Get max line width in a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, richtextbox

I'm trying to calculate the max horizontal scroll position of a RichTextBox, I'm aware that I could do something like:

```
Graphics g = richTextBox1.CreateGraphics();
float maxLineWidth = 0;
foreach(string line in richTextBox1.Lines) {
    float thisLineWidth = g.MeasureString(line, richTextBox1.Font).Width;
    if(thisLineWidth > maxLineWidth) {
        maxLineWidth = thisLineWidth;
    }
}
```

But is there a more efficient way?

There's a win api function `GetScrollRange` which is used like:

```
int min = 0;
int max = 0;
GetScrollRange(richTextBox1.Handle, SB_HORZ, out min, out max);
```

But this requires the RichTextBox to have scrollbars enabled, otherwise min/max will always be 0.
I do not want my RichTextBox to have the default scrollbars enabled.

Is there anything similar I could use which does not require scrollbars to be enabled?

Comment: Can you please clarify the problem or issue that you're trying to solve. What is the issue with the code you presented? You could shorten it to `var maxLineWidth = richTextBox1.Lines.Max(line => g.MeasureString(line, richTextBox1.Font).Width);`, but I don't think that's what you're asking.

Comment: Try something like this: `var flags = TextFormatFlags.NoClipping | TextFormatFlags.LeftAndRightPadding; int maxWidth = 0; using (var g = rtb1.CreateGraphics()) { maxWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText(g, rtb1.Text, rtb1.Font, new Size(int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue), flags).Width; }`. It should give you the max width of the RTB text without wordbreaks (btw, never use the RTB `Lines()` property).

Comment: Hi Pyon, if this issue has been solved you can answer your own question.