# Deternining how many pixels of text overflow the bounds of a textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, word-wrap

I have a function which I'm using to determine when lines of text exceed a textbox's horizontal/vertical bounds, it works perfectly for a textbox which has wordwrap disabled:

```
private bool OverflowsBounds(Direction dir) {
    int textSize;
    var flags = TextFormatFlags.NoClipping | TextFormatFlags.LeftAndRightPadding;
    using(var g = textbox1.CreateGraphics()) {
        if(dir == Direction.Horizontal) {
            if(WordWrap) return false;
            textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(g, textbox1.Text, textbox1.Font, new Size(int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue), flags).Width;
        } else {
            textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(g, textbox1.Text, textbox1.Font, new Size(int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue), flags).Height;
        }
    }
    int textBounds = dir == Direction.Horizontal ? textbox1.ClientRectangle.Width : textbox1.ClientRectangle.Height;

    return textSize >= textBound;
}
```

But when wordwrap is enabled, a line that is wrapped to a newline is considered a single line.
So if for example the textbox height is 100px and per line is 20px, a line that is wrapped to 3 lines will be 20px instead of 60px - so 2 copies of this wrapped line will be determined as taking up only 40px when they actually exceed the 100px bounds.

I tried making this change:

```
textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(g, textbox1.Text, textbox1.Font, new Size(WordWrap ? textbox1.ClientRectangle.Width : int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue), flags).Height;
```

And also tried using the WordBreak flag, but neither of these fix the problem.

Comment: Well, I'm glad you made good use of [that *example*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59992514/7444103), but you could have opened up the Docs and see what else  [TextFormatFlags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textformatflags) offers. In case you need to know the height of Text when WordWrap is enabled, you can add a Flag:  `TextFormatFlags.WordBreak` (and keep NoClipping). You can also add `TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl` for a more specific measure. You need to specify the `TextBox.ClientSize` as the proposed measure.

Comment: Note that the code snippet I proposed, is meant to measure the full extent of a Text when rendered with a specific Font. The container is not that relevant, as it's not relevant the `WordWrap` property value, since it's completely ignored. Also note that the Size you specify is an indication of a possible constraint. The ` TextFormatFlags` actually define how this measure is computed. Since a Size is provided **and** `TextFormatFlags.WordBreak` is specified, the Text is measured breaking the lines within those bounds. The Text height will overflow anyway, if there's enough text, of course.

Comment: Oh thank you very much for the explanation. I did actually try with WordBreak but with my testing I was using a string without spaces. It's working well with spaces and I don't really feel the need to figure out a fix for lines without spaces.